# forEach only posting last entry in 1d array javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to post all entries in a 1d array to a column in a google sheets. The array is the product of filtering two larger arrays and returning the names that do not appear on both lists.

below is an example of the generated array.

```
unPub = [fake name, test1, test2, test3]
```

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
    function unPublished(){
  const q3 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1111111111");
  const packAllergies = q3.getSheetByName("PACK_ALLERGIES");
  const packSrch = packAllergies.getRange("D5:D" + packAllergies.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const allergyNames = allergy.getRange("A2:A" + allergy.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  var  unPub = (packSrch.filter(e => !allergyNames.includes(e)));
  var sRow =  allergy.getLastRow()+1
  if (unPub.length > 0){
    unPub.forEach(e => allergy.getRange(sRow,1).setValue(e));
  }
}
```

I have tried a for loop to iterate over the list as well as `forEach` and still only get the last entry of the `unPub` array to post in the defined range.

How can I get each element in the array to post to the column starting at `sRow`?

Comment: All entries get posted, but you always use the same `sRow`, overwriting the value on every iteration, it looks like? Try putting `allergy.getLastRow()+1` instead of `sRow`, inside the `if`

Comment: I knew there was something wrong with the range but was not sure what it was. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

You don't need a loop to set values to the sheet. In fact it is not recommended, see [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices).

You need the following two steps:

- transform your row array into a column array:

  `unPub=unPub.map(v=>[v]);`

  because you want to set the data into a column.
- remove the `forEach` loop and directly pass the values with a single line:

  `allergy.getRange(sRow,1,unPub.length,1).setValues(unPub);`

### Solution:

```
function unPublished(){
  const q3 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1111111111");
  const packAllergies = q3.getSheetByName("PACK_ALLERGIES");
  const packSrch = packAllergies.getRange("D5:D" + packAllergies.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const allergyNames = allergy.getRange("A2:A" + allergy.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  var  unPub = (packSrch.filter(e => !allergyNames.includes(e)));
  var sRow =  allergy.getLastRow()+1;
  unPub=unPub.map(v=>[v]);
  allergy.getRange(sRow,1,unPub.length,1).setValues(unPub);
}
```

### Issue with your approach:

Besides performance issues which I described in the explanation section, your `forEach` loop does not work because you overwrite every value on the same cell. If you see, this part `allergy.getRange(sRow,1)` does not change in the for loop, given that `sRow` is constant.

If you want your approach to work, then you need to introduce an iterator `i` in the `forEach` loop and use that to iterate through the cells:

`unPub.forEach((e,i) => allergy.getRange(sRow+i,1).setValue(e));`

```
function unPublished(){
  const q3 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1111111111");
  const packAllergies = q3.getSheetByName("PACK_ALLERGIES");
  const packSrch = packAllergies.getRange("D5:D" + packAllergies.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const allergyNames = allergy.getRange("A2:A" + allergy.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  var  unPub = (packSrch.filter(e => !allergyNames.includes(e)));
  var sRow =  allergy.getLastRow()+1
  if (unPub.length > 0){
    unPub.forEach((e,i) => allergy.getRange(sRow+i,1).setValue(e));
  }
}
```

but I really recommend you the first approach I mentioned.

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much! Transforming the row array to column array is a lifesaver. I'd rather not have to use a loop if it can be avoided.

Comment: Glad it was helpful to you :) @Dan.db

Comment: Insanely helpful. I always have issues getting values from arrays. Using .map() to make that transformation is going to make JavaScript so much more fun and useful. I cannot say enough how grateful I am.